# How can I efficiently check many conditions and assign different ids where true?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code set up that needs to check many different conditions, like so:

```
cond = np.zeros_like(matrix1)
ids = np.where(matrix1 == value1)
cond[ids] = 1
ids2 = np.where(matrix2 == value2)
cond[ids2] = 2

...

idsn = np.where(matrixn == valuen)
cond[idsn] = n
```

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this.  In general, the conditions are not related to each other.  I should mention that some of the matrices may be re-used (i.e. condition 5 is checking for something with matrix2), and some of the conditions may be more complicated than just "matrix equals a number."  I'm looking for something kind of like:

```
for j, condition in enumerate(condition_list):
    ids = np.where(condition)
    cond[ids] = j
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what would be the problem with your proposed solution. Do you want something more elegant or flexible? Perhaps robust for different object types?

Comment: Are the matrices and values in a list? If not I suggest that you put them in one.

Comment: @zom-pro, I'm definitely looking for something more elegant.  Right now, this takes up about 40 lines of code, looks ugly, and I found a typo earlier because I'd mistyped one of the conditions.

Comment: @pzp A list is not a bad idea, but it wouldn't work exactly because some of the conditions are more complicated (i.e. matrix2 == value2 and matrix3 == value3)

Comment: @PatrickRinker Use a list of [``lambda``](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)s for the conditions then.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep it tidy, you could create a dictionary of conditions.

```
def eval_equal(a, b):
    return a == b

def eval_different(a, b):
    return a != b

def eval_combination(a, b):
    eval_equal(a, b) and eval_different(a, b)

evaluator = {}
evaluator['cond1'] = eval_equal
evaluator['cond2'] = eval_different
evaluator['cond3'] = eval_combination

my_matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
vector = [1, 2, 3]
conds = []
for cond, eval_func in evaluator.items():
    if eval_func(my_matrix, vector):
        conds.append(cond)

print(conds)
```

Then, as @pzp said, you could create a list of objects to be evaluated and feed them to the dictionary which will run through all the conditions. Also, it allows you to combine simple conditions (or more complex like a > 10 + b) because they are all functions.